# How can I change the header title when I click on a label in a Fragment (the title needs to be change to another one) but using same Fragment

Tags: java, android

How can I change the header title when I click on a label in a `Fragment` (the title needs to be changed to another one) but using the same `Fragment` for both.

Here when I click on the label, one additional view is added below the same fragment, but the header title needs to change.

My code

```
@Override
protected CharSequence getTopHeader() {
    return getString(R.string.ProfileSettings);
}
```

Comment: What's the header title & label you taking about? Are they the toolbar title and some button? Can you add more info?

Comment: It is a toolbar title. androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar